# Why does my sourceDirectories setting have no effect in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I'm reading the SBT [Getting Started](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html) guide. That page shows the `sourceDirectories` setting as an example.  To try it myself, I put the following in my `build.sbt` file, for a basic "hello world" project.

```
sourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(file("other"))
```

(Appending with `+=` or `++=` doesn't work either.)

I have source files in `<base-dir>/other` and in `<base-dir>/src/main/scala`. I ran `sbt` and typed `compile`.  It ignored the setting:

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Learning/Scala/proj1/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[error] /Learning/Scala/proj1/src/main/scala/hello.scala:7: not found: value Foo
[error]     println(Foo.foo)
```

The `Foo` object is defined in foo.scala in the `other` source directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tl;dr [The answer by @schleichardt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586961/1305344) is a valid one - you need to add the following to the `build.sbt` file:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("other")
```

The explanation boils down to inspecting the dependencies of the `compile` task. Use `inspect tree compile` to find them out.

```
[proj1]> inspect tree compile
[info] compile:compile = Task[sbt.inc.Analysis]
[info]   +-compile:compile::compileInputs = Task[sbt.Compiler$Inputs]
[info]   | +-compile:scalacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   | +-compile:sources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | +-*/*:sourcePositionMappers = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Function1[xsbti.Position, scala.Option[xsbti.Position]]]]
[info]   | +-*/*:maxErrors = 100
[info]   | +-*:compilers = Task[sbt.Compiler$Compilers]
[info]   | +-compile:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | | +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-compile:incCompileSetup = Task[sbt.Compiler$IncSetup]
[info]   | +-*/*:compileOrder = Mixed
[info]   | +-compile:dependencyClasspath = Task[scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]]
[info]   | +-compile:classDirectory = target/scala-2.10/classes
[info]   | +-*/*:javacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   |
[info]   +-compile:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]     +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]
```

As you can see, the task depends on the `compile:sources` task. The task in turn depends on the `compile:unmanagedSources` task that uses the `compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories` setting.

```
[proj1]> inspect tree compile:sources
[info] compile:sources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   +-compile:unmanagedSources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | +-compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories = List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/src/main/scala, /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/src/main/java, /Users/..
[info]   | | +-compile:javaSource = src/main/java
[info]   | | | +-compile:sourceDirectory = src/main
[info]   | | |   +-*:sourceDirectory = src
[info]   | | |   | +-*:baseDirectory = /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1
[info]   | | |   |   +-*:thisProject = Project(id: proj1, base: /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1, aggregate: List(), dependencies: List(), configurations: List(compile..
[info]   | | |   |
[info]   | | |   +-compile:configuration = compile
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-compile:scalaSource = src/main/scala
[info]   | | | +-compile:sourceDirectory = src/main
[info]   | | |   +-*:sourceDirectory = src
[info]   | | |   | +-*:baseDirectory = /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1
[info]   | | |   |   +-*:thisProject = Project(id: proj1, base: /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1, aggregate: List(), dependencies: List(), configurations: List(compile..
[info]   | | |   |
[info]   | | |   +-compile:configuration = compile
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-*:baseDirectory = /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1
[info]   | |   +-*:thisProject = Project(id: proj1, base: /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1, aggregate: List(), dependencies: List(), configurations: List(compile, runt..
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-*/*:excludeFilter = sbt.SimpleFileFilter@7ced8ea7
[info]   | +-*:baseDirectory = /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1
[info]   | +-*/*:unmanagedSources::includeFilter = sbt.SimpleFilter@1beb6bba
[info]   | +-*/*:sourcesInBase = true
[info]   |
[info]   +-compile:managedSources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]     +-compile:sourceGenerators = List()
[info]
```

The `compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories` setting references *"Unmanaged source directories, which contain manually created sources."*

```
[proj1]> inspect compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File] = List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/src/main/scala, /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/src/main/java, /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/other)
[info] Description:
[info]  Unmanaged source directories, which contain manually created sources.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/}proj1/compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:161
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/build.sbt:1
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:javaSource
[info]  compile:scalaSource
[info]  *:baseDirectory
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSources
[info]  compile:sourceDirectories
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  *:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  {.}/compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  {.}/*:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  */compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  */*:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] Related:
[info]  test:unmanagedSourceDirectories
```

The setting is of the `scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]` type and to append an element to the seq, you can use `+=` method.

Having said that, the `build.sbt` file should be as follows:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += (baseDirectory / "other").value
```

You don't have to use the `baseDirectory` setting, but it makes the base directory explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I think it will help others. In my case I've abandoned SBT and I hope to never return.

Comment: Oh, come on @RobN, sbt is so pleasantly hard so you have to have it on your CV to shine amongst other "common" devs during interviews :-) Seriously, sbt is so much different from make, ant, maven, gradle, buildr that it deserves time to learn it. What build tool do you use?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski.. I have been following you up on so for long and Thanks for great answers with detail explanation each time. I used to work on pyspark and facing lot of difficulties with Scala and SBT specially. Could you please also suggest your valuable advise on question below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084177/uber-jar-with-custom-folder-structure-with-intellij-and-sbt Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("other")
```