# SBT doesn't compile tests located in custom test source folders

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 3 test source folders in my project. I have added the following key to `build.sbt` (version of SBT: 1.2.1):

```
sourceDirectories in Test := baseDirectory { base =>
  Seq(
    base / "src/test/common/scala",
    base / "src/test/unit/scala",
    base / "src/test/functional/scala"
  )
}.value
```

SBT correctly recognized the folders:

```
sbt test:sourceDirectories
...
[info] Set current project to service (in build file:/myprojectfolder/)
[info] * /myprojectfolder/src/test/common/scala
[info] * /myprojectfolder/src/test/unit/scala
[info] * /myprojectfolder/src/test/functional/scala
```

but `test:compile` doesn't produce any test classes in `target/scala-2.11/test-classes` and in result `test` task doesn't run any tests.

I'm using ScalaTest 3.0.5 although that doesn't seem relevant.

Any ideas why SBT ignores test scala sources during compilation?

Comment: As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585437/why-does-my-sourcedirectories-setting-have-no-effect-in-sbt, try `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test`

Comment: This doc might also help. https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [manuzhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792668/manuzhang) for useful comments. Indeed the following change did the trick:

instead of

```
sourceDirectories in Test := baseDirectory { base =>
  Seq(
    base / "src/test/common/scala",
    base / "src/test/unit/scala",
    base / "src/test/functional/scala"
  )
}.value
```

I used

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test := baseDirectory { base =>
  Seq(
    base / "src/test/common/scala",
    base / "src/test/unit/scala",
    base / "src/test/functional/scala"
  )
}.value
```