# Uber jar with custom folder structure with IntelliJ and SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am fairly new to cloud and `SBT/IntelliJ`, So trying my luck with `IntelliJ & SBT` build environment to deploy my jar on data proc cluster.

Here's a screen shot of my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Code is quite simple with main defined in `'mytestmain'` which call another method defined in `'ReadYamlConfiguration'` which needed a `moultingyaml` dependency, which I have included as shown in my `build.sbt`.

Here's my `build.sbt` & `assembly.sbt` file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "MyTestProjectNew",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.test.processing.jobs.mytestmain.scala")
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.jcazevedo" %% "moultingyaml" % "0.4.2"
)

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

`assembly.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")
```

I created `assembly.sbt` to create Uber jar in order to include required dependencies and ran `'SBT assembly'` from Terminal. It has created a assembly jar file successfully, Which I was able to deploy and run successfully on Dataproc cluster.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster my-dataproc-cluster \
--region europe-north1 --class com.test.processing.jobs.mytestmain \
--jars gs://my-test-bucket/spark-jobs/MyTestProjectNew-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Code is working fine as expected with no issues.

Now I would like to have my own custom directory structure as shown below:

For example, I would like to have a folder name as `'spark-job'` with a sub dir named as `'SparkDataProcessing'` and then `src/main/scala` folder with packages and respective scala classes and objects etc.

my main method is defined in in package `'job'` within `'com.test.processing'` package.

What all changes do I need to make in `build.sbt`? I am looking for a detail explanation with `build.sbt` as a sample according to my project structure. Also please suggest what all needs to be included in `gitignore` file.

I am using `IntelliJ Idea 2020 community edition` and `SBT 1.3.3` version. I tried few things here and there but always ended up some issue with structure, jar or `build.sbt` issues.
I was expecting an answer something similar which is done in below post.

[Why does my sourceDirectories setting have no effect in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585437/why-does-my-sourcedirectories-setting-have-no-effect-in-sbt/20448611#20448611)

As you can see in below pic, the source directory has been changed.

```
spark-jobs/SparkDataProcessing/src/main/Scala
```

and when I am building this with below path, it's not working.

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

it works when I keep the default structure. like `src/main/scala`

[image: Custom Project Structure]

Answer (score 3):

You also need to change the package name after the `package` keyword at the top of affected files. However, if you refactor using IntelliJ (by creating the packages and then dragging the files into the package using the UI), then IntelliJ will do this for you.

Nothing else needs to be changed (`build.sbt` and related files can stay the same).

Finally, remember to change the `class` argument to reflect changes in entrypoint locations; you would pass `--class com.test.processing.jobs.job.mytestmain` instead of `--class com.test.processing.jobs.mytestmain`.

As for .gitignore: please take a look at an [example gitignore file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/.gitignore) which includes:

- output directories containing "target"
- IntelliJ directories such as ".idea"

[Another gitignore example](https://gist.github.com/owainlewis/152b4a370ca8423e1c9f) ignores all .class files generated by the compiler, another approach. You should include all files which are generated dynamically, where changes do not matter to other developers.

Comment: My build.sbt still would need a change since default project structure is change now.

Comment: This does not answer to my actual question. you see I have two sub directories and then src/main/Scala where my actual codes or main method lies. so if I had to compile my source than what would be the path of my source dir?